# Google sheets Find next numeric value from the colnums

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, filter, google-query-language

I have two rows with SKUs, one comes from one database, and another one from another one. As you can see in the visual example SKUs with values 1, 2, 4 & 5 are present in both databases.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlTCr.png

I start with number 1 and I need a formula that would bring up the next valid number (in this case number 2) that is present in both columns.

I would need a formula that would do the following:
If I lookup 1 it should bring 2
If I lookup 2 it should bring 4
If I lookup 4 it should bring 5

Thank you in advance

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Here you go: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v3SrNCL-besVtqovnagewE8PvvOzk4N114nAiFOImGs/edit?usp=sharing I have added the desired output below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
={FILTER(B2:B16, COUNTIF(E2:E16, B2:B16)), 
 {QUERY(FILTER(B2:B16, COUNTIF(E2:E16, B2:B16)), "offset 1", ); ""}}
```

[image]